# Term-by-term integration of complex power series

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading *Complex Variables and Applications* by Brown and Churchill, and I get stuck in Section 65.  Suppose

$$S(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (z-z_0)^n$$

is a function defined on the interior of the circle of convergence of the above power series.  I know that $S(z)$ is analytic, and the following theorem holds.

> Let $C$ be a closed curve in the circle of convergence in the power series $S(z)$, and $g(z)$ is continuous on $C$.  Then the term-by-term intergration of $g(z) S(z)$ holds. i.e.
>
> $$\int_C g(z) S(z) \,\mathrm{d}z = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \int_C g(z)(z-z_0)^n \,\mathrm{d}z.$$

I *can't* understand the following claim.

> If $\lvert g(z) \rvert = 1$ for each value of $z$ in the open disk bounded by the circle of power series $S(z)$, the fact that $(z-z_0)^n$ is entire when $n = 0,1,\dots$ ensures that
>
> $$\int_C g(z)(z-z_0)^n \,\mathrm{d}z = \int_C (z-z_0)^n \,\mathrm{d}z = 0.$$

I tried thinking about

1. Maximum modulus principle

   - The modulus of $g$ is *constant* in the open disk, so there's a *local minimum* of the modulus of $g$, so $g$ is constant.
   - But then I realized that $g$ is merely *continuous*.  It is possible that $g$ *isn't* holomorphic.
2. $$\left\lvert\int_C f\right\rvert\le\int_C\left\lvert f\right\rvert$$

   - \begin{align}\left\lvert\int_C g(z)(z-z_0)^n\,\mathrm{d}z\right\rvert&\le\int_C\left\lvert g(z)\right\rvert\left\lvert(z-z_0)^n\right\rvert\,\mathrm{d}z\\
     &=\int_C\left\lvert(z-z_0)^n\right\rvert\,\mathrm{d}z\end{align}
   - But I *can't* get an integral whose value is zero.

I need this theorem to establish the fact that $S(z)$ is holomorphic in its circle of convergence (with Morera's theorem).

Comment: Is $g$ real valued?

Comment: I suppose *not*.
For your convenience, it is the $g$ on p.208 in Section 59 of the 7th ed. of the book
http://www.math.s.chiba-u.ac.jp/~yasuda/ippansug/CV-bookfi.pdf

Comment: I assume that is a typographical error in the book.  What the author probably meant is to *apply* the first formula to the special case $g(z) = 1$, on order to prove that the power series $S(z)$ is analytic in the interior of the circle of convergence.

Comment: Thank for your comment at first.  I think about this for hours.  If $g$ is continuous but *not* holomorphic, with $|g(z)| = 1$ in an open neighbourhood, I can *neither* prove that $g(z) \equiv 1 \,\forall z$ in the open neighbourhood, *nor* give a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that is a typographical error in the book
and should be $g(z) = 1$ instead of $|g(z)| = 1$.

What the author probably meant is to *apply* the first formula to the special case $g(z) = 1$, in order to prove that the power series $S(z)$ is analytic in the interior of the circle of convergence.